# How to adjust the boxshadow such that it is the full length of the parent div?

Tags: html, css

i want the boxshadow to fit the entire width of the parent div that is wrapper.

i have a div with class emptydiv and i have added box shadow only to top. doing so it will create a box shadow that is cut at the edges like in picture below.

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 32px;
        width: 316px;
        height: 225px;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
        border-radius: 16px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .container_one {
        height: 101px;
        width: 316px;
        padding: 16px 6px 16px 22px;
        border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
        box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
        margin: 0px -6px 0px -6px;  
    } 

    .description {
        height: 42px;
        width: 289px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        color: black;
        display: flex;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 400;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
    `; 

     .container_two {
         padding: 16px 0px 16px 10px;
         max-height: 108px;
         display: flex;
         flex-wrap: wrap;
         overflow-x: hidden;

         & > div {
             margin-right: 4px;
             margin-bottom: 16px;
         }
     }

     .empty_div{
         height: 32px;
         width: 316px;
         border-radius: 0 0 16px 16px;
         box-shadow: 0px -6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
         margin: 0px -6px 0px -6px;
     }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container_one">
        this has boxshadow that is as expected
            <span class="text">sometext</span>
            <div class="description">some big description</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container_two"> 
       this has boxshadow cut at right side
        </div>
        <div class="empty_div"/>
    </div>
```

Now the problem is how can i set margin on empty_div such that it fits the entire width of wrapper div. right now its cut on the right edge as shown in picture above.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: add  overflow-x: hidden; to .wrapper class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the static `width` property for the containers with the shadowbox property and it should all work out.

Please review the modified example below. I modified the CSS so it is compatible with the browser as I think you copied and pasted the raw style SASS, LESS or one of those processors.

```css
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 32px;
    width: 316px;
    height: 225px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    border-radius: 16px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    opacity: 1;
}

.container_one {
    height: 101px;
    padding: 16px 6px 16px 22px;
    border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    margin: 0px -6px 0px -6px;  
} 

.description {
    height: 42px;
    width: 289px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
} 

 .container_two {
     padding: 16px 0px 16px 10px;
     max-height: 108px;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 
 .container_two > div {
         margin-right: 4px;
         margin-bottom: 16px;
     }

 .empty_div{
     height: 32px;
     border-radius: 0 0 16px 16px;
     box-shadow: 0px -6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
     margin: 0px -6px 0px -6px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container_one">//this has boxshadow that is as expected
        <span class="text">sometext</span>
        <div class="description">some big description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container_two"> //this has boxshadow cut at right side
    </div>
    <div class="empty_div"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but this is still not working for me. not sure why the code is all same

Comment: yes removing the width for emptydiv worked. thanks.